# Freetype 2 unable to open .ttf/.ttc font files

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to draw some text using OpenGL on iPad.So I am using Freetype 2 library to load font files.Like as followed:

```
        FT_New_Face(ft, "/System/Library/Fonts/Geneva.dfont", 0, &face)
```

The compiler does not throw any error in opening the file but when I try to do this:

```
        FT_New_Face(ft, "/System/Library/Fonts/HelveticaLight.ttf", 0, &face)
```

I get the error as:

```
        "FT_Stream_Open: could not open `/System/Library/Fonts/HelveticaLight.ttf'
         Could not open font"
```

I am using the Freetype 2 library for iOS from here:

https://github.com/cdave1/freetype2-ios

I have read that Feetype 2 supports TrueType fonts but I don't know the reason why it is unable to open .ttf/.ttc files.

Thanks

Comment: This might sound stupid, but are you sure the funt you are opening is there? This sounds kind of like I/O error. Also, are you sure the compiler reports the error? Shouldn't it be error at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Try to look for the path to the font in CGFontCache.plist:

```
NSDictionary *fontsDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"/System/Library/Fonts/CGFontCache.plist"];
NSDictionary* traitsDict = [fontsDict valueForKey:@"TraitMappings"];
NSDictionary *arialMappingDict = [traitsDict valueForKey:@"Arial"];
NSDictionary *namesDict = [fontsDict valueForKey:@"Names"];
NSString* arialPathSting = [namesDict valueForKey:[arialMappingDict valueForKey:@"Plain"]];
FT_Error error = FT_New_Face(ft, [arialPathSting UTF8String], 0, &face)
```

Works fine for iOS device, but has issues on simulator. Actually, there I wasn't able to find CGFontCache.plist on simulator.